# How to divide a double value without rounding in swift?

Tags: swift, double

I have to divide a big double number by another in my application which will show 8 digit after floating point. Here is the swift code:

```
let firstValue:Double = 355531194300085860
let secondValue:Double = 100000000
let result = String(format: "%.8f", firstValue/secondValue)
print("value: \(result)")
```

I am expecting the output as **3555311943.00085860** but compiler giving output like this **3555311943.00085878** . Why this is happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Are you aware that `Double` has a limited precision (approx 16 decimal digits)?

Comment: I am a new learner and I actually didn't know in swift Double has a limited precision of 16 digits. It actually has given me as an assignment to do. Will you please tell me how to calculate this division and make a proper output?

Comment: Are the numbers you want to divide always multiplies of 10?

Comment: Not actually, it will be a big random number every time.

Comment: @MuhammadArifulIslam, `Double` ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating-point number with double precision) in **all** languages are like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
let firstValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: "355531194300085860")
let secondValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: "100000000")
let result = firstValue.dividing(by: secondValue)
print(result)
```

Result: 3555311943.0008586

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But isn’t it the correct result? The expected result in the question is unrealistic. The result of the calculation won’t be returned with some arbitrary number of trailing zeroes after the decimal point.

Comment: The value does not match with the expected output, what if I want the result with the arbitrary number?

Comment: @Magnas, there're two different problems here: division with proper precision (this answer solves) and proper formatting output to string (answer doesn't solve, but it's quite trivial to expand existing answer to solve it too).

Comment: In Swift you may want to use `Decimal` instead. It is simple struct (instead of a pointer to a class instance), and can be used with operators: `let result = firstValue / secondValue`